# Manipulate DOM with JS. Add button & Link

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This script is supposed to add a button and the button needs to link to xyz.com. I am able to get the button to display, but it does not link. Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = 'Watch Now';
document.getElementById('buttoncontainer').appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").href = "http://www.cnn.com/";
</script>
```

Thanks,
Udi

Comment: A `button` does not have an `href` attribute (that actually does anything)

Comment: Buttons aren't the same as links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `button` to navigate, you'll have to add a bit more than what you have because `button` elements don't have an `href` attribute and don't produce navigation by default. You'll need to set up a `click` event handling callback function for that.

Also, don't use `.innerText` as it is non-standard. Use **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** instead.

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
</div>
<script>
  var container = document.getElementById('buttonContainer');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.textContent = 'Watch Now';
  
  // Buttons don't have an href. You need to set up a click event handler
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    location = "https://cnn.com"; // Navigate to new page
  });
  
  // Add button to page
  container.appendChild(btn);
</script>
```

If you want a hyperlink (`<a>`), then you can work with `href`:

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
</div>
<script>
  var container = document.getElementById('buttonContainer');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.textContent = 'Watch Now';
  a.href = "https://cnn.com";
  
  // Add hyperlink to page
  container.appendChild(a);
</script>
```

**NOTE:**

Neither of these will actually navigate you to CNN here in the Stack Overflow code snippet environment, due to security restrictions, but the code will work in your own environment.

Comment: I've seen `textContent` and `innerText` and `innerHTML` and wasn't totally clear which was the new shiny best one to use (if any). Thanks for the link. I didn't know that `textContent` auto-encoded HTML. That's really snazzy!

Comment: @Anthony `.textContent` is for getting/setting text that does not include HTML that you want parsed. `.innerHTML` is for getting/setting text that does contain HTML that you want parsed and `innerText` is legacy code that is non-standard and should not be used. Good luck and don't forget to mark my answer as "the" answer.

Comment: sorry, buddy. Not the OP. Just was glad to have had an excuse thanks to your answer to finally mess around with `innerText` and see how it works.